# REST and URI Caching

Tags: rest, caching, uri, hateoas

As I understand it, using a [hypertext-driven](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) RESTful Web service, a client is not supposed to know anything about server URI layout except for a couple of well-known entry points. This is supposed to enable the server to control its own URI space and reduce coupling with the client.

When a client for the service sends a successful request to create a new resource, the service responds 201 CREATED and gives the URI at which the new resource can be accessed in the Location header field.

Should a client be allowed to store this URI to enable direct access to the resource in the future and if so for how long? If URIs are cached by the client, this seems to be setting up a situation in which every time the server changes its URI layout, it will need to make sure a permanent redirect gets served when old URIs are accessed. Otherwise the client breaks. Over several years, this system of redirects could get out of hand.

This situation would not appear to have given the server much more control over its URI space than a REST-RPC hybrid approach using URI templates.

There's a lot of information available about caching representations, but what about caching URIs in hypertext-driven RESTful systems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember as Tim Berners-Lee said, "cool URLs don't change". Once the server hands out a URI to the client, it is now the server's job to keep the URI working in the future by (for instance) sending a Moved-Permanently response in case the URI changed and someone requests the old one.

This is actually what encourages many to design opaque URIs, such as based on database ids or timestamps, rather than using some human-readable property of the resource in the URI. Anything that people understand, they will want to change.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I found the quote in this oldie but goodie: http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI

Answer (score 2):

Yes the client should be allowed to store the URI.  For as long as it wants. As Licky mentioned a smart client can use a Moved-Permanently response to update its bookmarks.

If you think about it, we have the best possible situation.  You can change the urls on the server, whilst choosing to still support old clients for as long as we choose, and intelligent clients can effectively auto update themselves to the new urls.

How long you choose to continue to support those old urls is really a decision that needs to be made based on the existing clients and the ease with which they can be maintained.

For me this is a huge improvement over the versioning issues with RPC style interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I think there's a subcomponent to the answers that I see here that hasn't been addressed.

Remember that you're not retrieving the resource from the server, but you're retrieving a REPRESENTATION of a resource.  The resource itself may have its primary identifier change, or be rehomed, or whatever, but the representation that was returned to the client on resource creation may (or may not be) valid independently; it's all a matter of situation.

As an example, consider a moderated content upload system; a user may have the ability to upload content for consideration by the moderators that may eventually cause the content to be exposed to a wider audience / market.  On initial upload, the server may respond with a URI that directs to (say) "users/{userid}/uploaded/{contentid}" for that representation of that content.  At some point, the moderators may decide to promote the content to a "front page"; that representation of the content may then be available at the URI of "content/{contentid}"; that should not prevent the original uploader from accessing their data at "users/{userid}/uploaded/{contentid}"; nothing says that there needs to be a permanent redirect, and in fact, there's good reason for there not to be; if the user decides they want to remove the content, they should be able to perform a DELETE on the content; it's probably much preferential to have users doing DELETEs to the content representations from their own "uploaded" locations.  However, if the terms of the site indicate that user rights to content uploaded are revoked (not uncommon) it might make sense to have the moderation promotion process effectively remove the content from the user's own area, causing a "permanent move".

It's really entirely dependent upon the specific situation; the validity of a cached URI is completely dependent upon the server's policies.  At the least, I'd think that a request to an invalid URI (that may have previously been valid) should cause a response (consistent with HATEOAS) that can allow the client to "rediscover" the resource (representation) they were looking for; at the very least, a link to the entry-point.

Answer (score 0):

Since one of the principals of REST is that resources are addressable, it seems perfectly acceptable for a client to keep track of the address (URI) for a given resource.  Resource URIs should be one of the "well known entry points" you referred to.

Comment: No no no no! The server must be able to manage its own URI space. If the client can store URIs, then the server can't modify its URI space without potentially breaking clients. In some cases it's allowable to cache, depending on the application, but it's not a clear cut case as you imply. Resource URIs are also not entry-points, they are end-points, and they should not be "well known"!

Comment: Hrm.  You're right.  I went and read the Fielding article you linked to, and it's clear I don't have my head wrapped around REST as well as I thought.  I'll do more studying before giving out any more advice.